# how to print a two diffetent array element in single tr using json in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json

I want to print a two arrays in a single tr. My json is like

```
[{"group_name":"Ecofresh","id":"19","userId":"19","device_details":[{"userid":"19","unit_id":"35","unit_name":"Test123","mac_id":"EB9F5E5727D7","m2xa":"95005c74d3cb33ca320e4b92cdee617d","m2xd":"5a00144b70bda43667498cf44677ad3e","mdlno":"Mtemp","group_id":"19","watchstat":"0","battery":"3.02","network":"-58","updatetime":"2018-06-22 11:50:20 ","unitShow":[{"unit":"celcius"},{"unit":"%"}],"channels":[{"id":"106865","chkey":"ch1","chvalue":"30","updatetime":"2018-06-22 11:50:20 ","unit_id":"35"},{"id":"106866","chkey":"ch2","chvalue":"69","updatetime":"2018-06-22 11:50:20 ","unit_id":"35"}]},{"userid":"19","unit_id":"46","unit_name":"T4","mac_id":"E51068E8A28C","m2xa":"f6852dfc4b49908c02a3d7893eba6331","m2xd":"4c798928f651626ccb2a30ffbd4820c3","mdlno":"Mtemp","group_id":"19","watchstat":"0","battery":"3.04","network":"-62","updatetime":"2018-06-22 11:50:21 ","unitShow":[{"unit":"celcius"},{"unit":"celcius"}],"channels":[{"id":"106867","chkey":"ch1","chvalue":"30","updatetime":"2018-06-22 11:50:21 ","unit_id":"46"},{"id":"106868","chkey":"ch2","chvalue":"69","updatetime":"2018-06-22 11:50:21 ","unit_id":"46"}]},{"userid":"19","unit_id":"47","unit_name":"T2","mac_id":"C0A02FF440A1","m2xa":"ed2e2b818fbe24584c6a7b50b3db8d9e","m2xd":"4e2f9beb516da0a65361770fd2276c0d","mdlno":"Mtemp","group_id":"19","watchstat":"0","battery":"3","network":"-62","updatetime":"2018-06-22 11:50:24 ","unitShow":[{"unit":"%"},{"unit":"%"}],"channels":[{"id":"106869","chkey":"ch1","chvalue":"30","updatetime":"2018-06-22 11:50:24 ","unit_id":"47"},{"id":"106870","chkey":"ch2","chvalue":"68","updatetime":"2018-06-22 11:50:24 ","unit_id":"47"}]}]}]
```

and code is.

```
<tr  ng-repeat="item3 in item1.channels"  ng-show="item3.chkey !=null "&&"item3.value!= null"><td> {{item3.chkey}}={{item3.chvalue}}</td> </tr>
```

want to show element **unitShow** next to the chvalue. means for first row i want to print

ch1=30 celcius
ch2=69 %

like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the $index to access element from the first array.

```
<tr  ng-repeat="item3 in item1.channels"  ng-show="item3.chkey !=null && item3.value!= null"><td> {{item3.chkey}}={{item3.chvalue}} {{item1.unitShow[$index].unit}}</td></tr>
```